# Use sed to replace each white space with a backslash

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just want to escape spaces in windows filepath. I'm trying this:

```
echo "111  1111 "| sed -e "s/[[:space:]]/\\ /g"
```

that only match spaces but do not replace.

Comment: I agree, the title is misleading ;-)  But "ecran[sic] spaces in ... filepath" is pretty clear. `echo "111  1111 "` has a fixed number of whitespace, so I don't really get your quesiton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use double quotes, `bash` interprets `\\` and outputs `\` which is then again interpreted from `sed` together with the following space to just the space.

So you need one more backslash:

```
echo "111  1111 " | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]/\\\ /g"
```

but better to use single quotes to prevent the bash interpreting:

```
echo "111  1111 " | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\\ /g'
```

Output:

```
111\ \ 1111\
```

---

**Alternative method:**

If you have the file path as a variable, you can use Shell methods:

```
path="111  1111 "
echo ${path// /\\ }
```

Comment: What would the out put be like?

Comment: +1 for Alternative method.

Comment: nice method with variable, thanks. It is useful for my .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

`[[:space:]]` doesn’t match just spaces but rather *all whitespace characters* including tabs and line breaks. If you really want that, GNU `sed` (like in Ubuntu) has the shorthand class `\s` for it:

```
sed 's_\s_\\&_g'
```

This `s`ubstitutes every (`g`) whitespace character (`\s`, matches spaces, tabs and newlines embedded in the pattern/hold spaces) in every line with a backslash (`\\`) and itself – `&` is the whole matched pattern. I use a different delimiter because slashes and backslashes always look confusing together; `s/\s/\\&/g` is of course valid as well.

If you want to replace only *space* characters, rather use:

```
sed 's_ _\\&_g'
```

#### Example run

```
$ echo "111  1111 " | sed 's_ _\\&_g'
111\ \ 1111\
```

For further reading on character classes see [here on regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works too. an unusual form of regex. not so widely common?

Comment: @Yurij I didn’t use any regex, do you mean `&` for the entire matched pattern? That’s actually quite common…